# Are almond fruits edible?

Tags: foraging, edible

I went to get almonds at Walgreens and my friend said he would get me a bunch from the beach.  And he proceeded to give me 4 [almond fruits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almond).  I had seen these many times on the trees (here in San Juan Puerto Rico) but I wasn't sure they were edible.  They smell like peaches and they do not taste bad.

Comment: Buena pregunta :) Love him or hate him Bear Grylls describes and eats these on one of his tropical island survival shows, the whole thing is fine to eat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are eating fruits like these, you aren't eating true almonds.  These are tropical almonds, [Terminalia catappa](http://the3foragers.blogspot.com/2012/02/wild-edibles-in-hawaii-tropical-almonds.html), and the entire fruit and nut are edible.